# Efficient cell formula counting of substrings in a range of cells

Tags: regex, count, google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

I have a Google spreadsheet with two columns: A and C. Column A has over a thousand rows of names/subjects in their own cells, and Column C has several hundred rows with a variable combination of the above names/subjects in its various cells, with each name/subject separated from the others by a semicolon.  Each of these columns gains new entries frequently throughout the course of the day.

As a very simplified visual example of the setup:

```
**Column A: Names  | Column B: Occurrences | Column C: List**

A2: Adam           | B2: [Blank]           | C2: Charles; Adam

A3: Bob            | B3: [Blank]           | C3: Adam

A4: Charles        | B4: [Blank]           | C4: Smith, Charles

A5: Smith, Charles | B5: [Blank]           | C5: Bob Evans

A6: Bob Evans      | B6: [Blank]           | C6: Smith, Charles; Charles; Bob

A7: [etc.]         | B7: [Blank]           | C7: Bob Evans; Charles; Bob

A8: [etc.]         | B8: [Blank]           | C8: [etc.]
```

Currently, I’m using the following formula to count the number of times that each string from Column A (here, A2) appears as a substring in Column C (here, C2 through C7):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2="","",(SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE($C$2:$C$7,"([\(\)\?])", ""),"(\w+),{0,1}\s+(\w+)","$1$2"),".*(^|\s)"& trim(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE($A2,"([\(\)\?])", ""),"(\w+),{0,1}\s+(\w+)","$1$2"))&"(;|$).*")))))`

This gives the correct totals, but it seems to be incredibly processing heavy once you scale up; changing or adding any one entry to Column C causes the entire sheet to recalculate its thousands of entries, and it takes several minutes for it to turn out the new totals.  Many of the REGEXREPLACE values are used here because some of the entries have punctuation like “()” and “?”, on account of cells like “Erōs”, “Olympic Games (23rd : 1984 : Los Angeles, Calif.)”, and “Thomas, Aquinas, Saint, 1225?-1274”.

The closest counting alternative that I’ve come up with is the following:

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(C$2:C$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C$2:C$7,A2,"")))/LEN(A2))`

Testing shows that this much simpler formula can recalculate the whole sheet in a few seconds, but it doesn’t actually count the entries correctly.  In the above example of C2-C7, it would give totals of 4 and 5 for “Bob” and “Charles” because it doesn’t distinguish between “Bob” and “Bob Evans” or “Charles” and “Smith, Charles.”  It should properly find 2 and 3 respectively.

Is there an effective way to adjust the above formula or create a new one which will count all the substrings properly—limiting the sums to exact matches to Column A as they're found between semicolons in Column C—without causing the sheet’s calculations to freeze up for several minutes at a time?  Regular expressions were the route I first ended up taking, but I expect that those operations are the reason that it takes so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRIM(A2)=TRIM(SPLIT($C$2:$C$8,";")))
```

Comment: This is excellent, yes!  My only question is whether there’s a way to have it search an unlimited range without returning an error.  Using ($C$2:$C) instead of ($C$2:$C$8) gives a result of #VALUE, “Error Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty.”  I haven’t figured out the correct way to layer an IF statement in to manage that.

Comment: `C$2:INDEX(C$2:C, CountA(C$2:C))` or `C$2:C&" "` The first one gives better performance( if you can figure out how to use it).  If you just want count of each unique entity, check my other solution below.

Comment: I believe that's done the trick; thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started in the right direction:

```
=QUERY(C$2:C,"SELECT count(C) WHERE C CONTAINS ('"&A2&"') OR C CONTAINS upper('"&A2&"') OR C CONTAINS lower('"&A2&"')", -1)
```

Comment: You could make it all upper to simplify. `=QUERY(C$2:C,"SELECT count(C) WHERE upper(C) CONTAINS upper('"&A2&"') ")`

Comment: These both look very helpful in counting accurately, but at the moment when I place either formula in B1 it only pulls up the number of "Adam" occurrences in B2 instead of counting for each column A instance and displaying their sums in the corresponding B cells.  I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with SQL and Google Queries to identify the problem.

Comment: Simple Fix, *Query function likes to label its data set*, so to turn it off is:   
    =QUERY(C$2:C,"SELECT count(C) WHERE C CONTAINS ('"&A2&"') OR C CONTAINS upper('"&A2&"') OR C CONTAINS lower('"&A2&"') __label count(C) ''"__,)

Answer (score 1):

Try this too:
Somewhere in 
Y1:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(SPLIT(C2:C6,";")& ""), "")))), "select Col1,Count (Col1) group by Col1")
```

Comment: Nifty approach.  What purpose does the tennis racket emoji serve here in `& ""), "")`?

Comment: @A. K. It serves as a unique differentiating entity. The formula needs a unique marker on the text to separate after joining them as one. I could also use `%` or any other symbol. But then you also might have `%` somewhere in your text. If so, the formula will fail. But I believe there's no chance of you having a tennis racket emoji anywhere in your text. Do you?

Comment: I thought that might be the case; thanks for the clarification!